# Customize dropdown-list height in IE8

Tags: html, css, forms

[image]

Im trying to change the **height + padding** for my ddl :

I saw in facebook that all they are doing is:

[image]

However - in my testing:

http://jsbin.com/acijuv/2/edit

is working in chrome, but not in IE8 (facebook page **does** show it fine in my ie8). Any help?

Comment: I looked it up in IE8 and it shows the spacing. or is there any other thing you wanted to do ?

Comment: @EvilP please post your comment as answer. my browser was in quirks mode.

Comment: just added the answer ! Was this your solution or is there anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up in IE8 and it shows the spacing. or is there any other thing you wanted to do ?